# dependency issue installing mcgw

Tags: centos, openssl

I'm trying to install a package called mcgw onto a centos 7.7 machine. And I'm getting a dependency problem:

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mcgw.x86_64 0:1.0.010-0 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so()(64bit) for package: mcgw-1.0.010-0.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so()(64bit) for package: mcgw-1.0.010-0.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mcgw-1.0.010-0.x86_64 (/mcgw-1.0.010-0.x86_64)
           Requires: libssl.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: mcgw-1.0.010-0.x86_64 (/mcgw-1.0.010-0.x86_64)
           Requires: libcrypto.so()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

But I have openssl and openssl libraries installed.

```
openssl11-libs-1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64
openssl-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64
openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64
python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1-1.el7.noarch
openssl11-1.1.1c-2.el7.x86_64`

How do I get around this problem?
```

Comment: Those dependencies look wrong. Was this package even built for CentOS 7?

Comment: I think so. The earlier version of the same package installed with no problem: `mcgw-1.0.007-0.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: You should try removing those exclusions you mentioned in the other question.

Comment: I have done that already.

Comment: What was the yum output _after_ doing that?

Comment: Same is what I have in the OP for this question.

Comment: At this point I'm leaning towards the package not being built correctly. Those dependencies should be libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) or libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for openssl 1.1. That package doesn't seem to be available publicly, so I don't know where you got it, but my next step would be to contact them.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try to contact them to see if it was built correctly. It's someone at oracle I believe but my company has some contacts there.

Comment: Installing it via nodeps works apparently. Found some documentation suggesting that. Thanks.